# How to make sure the model is within options boundary?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I have a 2 selects handled by angularjs and the related controller.

The optins if the second select depends on the user selection in the first select.

I have this code, as follows:

```
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Stade<br/>
                        <select data-ng-options="s.displayName for s in stages" 
                                data-ng-model="accidentSearchSelectedStage"
                                onChange="javascript:getAccidentsModel(this)"
                                >
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Organe<br/>
                        <select data-ng-options="o.displayName for o in organs | filter:accidentsSearch(accidentSearchSelectedStage, null, null, accidentsDiagnosticsMenu)" 
                                data-ng-model="accidentSearchSelectedOrgan"
                                onChange="javascript:getAccidentsModel(this)"
                                >
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

EDIT 1: added filter code snippet

```
$scope.accidentsSearch = function( stage, organ, symptom, accidentsDiagnosticsMenu ) {

    if (organ==null && symptom ==null) {
        console.log("------>filter organs for criteria stage: "+stage.displayName+", "+organ+", "+symptom);

        return function( organToCheck ) {
            if (!accidentsDiagnosticsMenu) return false;    // not yet prepared

            organToCheck =  organToCheck.displayName;
            var pruned = accidentsDiagnosticsMenu[stage.displayName];
            //console.log("Exploring pruned with "+stage.displayName+": "+JSON.stringify(pruned));

            for (var o in pruned) {
                // Find one with same organs?
                var keep = (o == organToCheck);
                if (keep) {
                    //console.log("Checking organs "+o+"=="+organToCheck+" for stage "+ stage.displayName+ ", so keep = "+keep);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        };
    }
    else
    if (symptom == null) {
        console.log("------>filter for criteria stage/organ : "+stage.displayName+", "+organ.displayName+", "+symptom);
        return function(symptomToCheck ) {
```

Q1) This works nice except it sometime selects an empty additional option in the second select, depending on the previous selected value it had.

How to fix this?

Q2) I need to execute legacy javascript code anytime a new selection is made. Is the 'onchange' attribute the correct way to do, or is there an angularjs way to do it?

**EDIT 2: $watch path exploration**

I explored a solution with a $watch on the model connected to each select as follows:

```
$scope.$watch('accidentSearchSelectedStage', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log("accidentSearchSelectedStage changed from "+oldValue.id+" to "+newValue.id);
});

$scope.$watch('accidentSearchSelectedOrgan', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log("accidentSearchSelectedOrgan changed from "+oldValue.id+" to "+newValue.id);
    //$scope.accidentSearchSelectedSymptom = $scope.symptoms[0];
});
```

The logs are ok, but I'm stuck at this point for 2 reasons:

1. What is the time diagram between the selection of say stage, and
   the execution of the filter?
2. Where and how to code to check the
   value of organ and symptom are inbounds?

Comment: Off-topic, but you should look at ngChange instead of onChange. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange

Comment: Ok, but getAccidentsModel does not belong(yet) to the controller as it is legacy javascript code.

Comment: Ahhh, that makes sense. tootle-loo

Answer (score 0):

If the model is set to something other than an available option, the `select` directive will automatically create an option for that value. Otherwise it won't know which one should be selected. Theoretically it could be the first one, but I'm sure the Angular guys have a valid reason for doing this.

Anyway, you basically just need to bootstrap your data in your controller to make sure that if it doesn't have a valid option, just set it to the default one.

E.g.

```
var data = getDataFromSomeSource();
var validOptions = ['foo','bar','default'];
if(validOptions.indexOf(data.option) < 0) {
    data.option = 'default';
}
```

RE: #2 - `onchange` is probably the easiest way to do that for now, no point in adding additional/unnecessary non-angular code if this is just temporary until you port everything over.

Comment: I added the filter code snipet in the question as I'm wondering where to add the code you suggested.

Comment: Looks like you don't have a default value, so just set `$scope.accidentSearchSelectedStage` to whatever you want the default to be. Beginning of the controller is usually where I put the bootstrap stuff like that unless it's from an AJAX call.

Comment: This is the point: how to setup a different default value depending on the user choice in the first select?

Comment: I did this, but was not able to address my issue. Give me 5 mins to update my question with the watch.